# What are use cases for git namespaces?

Tags: git, namespaces

I recently learned about [git namespaces](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces) and currently trying to grok it. In what situations namespaces can be useful in git?

Comment: _Storing multiple repositories as namespaces of a single repository avoids storing duplicate copies of the same objects, such as when storing multiple branches of the same source._ [git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces#_description](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitnamespaces#_description)

Comment: @GeorgeCummins what are use cases for "storing duplicate copies of the same objects" and "storing multiple branches of the same source"? I must admit: I'm a little stupid. This sentence makes me feel even more stupid and confused.

Comment: And, of course, I read the manual before asking the question. That's why I'm asking: I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be useful for a Git service like GitHub or [git.kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/) where a repository is forked many times.  Each fork is almost identical, so if only one object store is used for all forks then the service might enjoy considerable space savings and cache performance improvements.

The service could implement this via a lightweight wrapper around Git that automatically prepends the name of the repository to the `GIT_NAMESPACE` value.

Other than that, I'm not sure why one would use namespaces.